# Google Maps - Remove markers before update

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am adding multiple markers from the JSON file. And it works like : There is a list of shop in JSON with some address. I have provided **Input box** where  user would enter any postal address. Now whatever address user will insert, based on that address google map will add markers to it(if distance is less than 10 KM). Here is the code:

```
var map;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var mapOptions = {
   zoom: 6
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
      mapOptions);

$(".search-btn").click(function(){

   $.getJSON('path to json', function(data) { 
       $.each( data.markers, function(i, value) { 

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var postal = $("#postal").val(); //Take address from the user

            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': postal }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                    var platitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var plongitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                    //calculate distance
                      var plat1 = Math.PI * platitude/180;
                      var plat2 = Math.PI * value.latitude/180;
                      var plon1 = Math.PI * plongitude/180;
                      var plon2 = Math.PI * value.longitude/180;
                      var ptheta = plongitude-value.longitude;
                      var pradtheta = Math.PI * ptheta/180;
                      var pdist = Math.sin(plat1) * Math.sin(plat2) + Math.cos(plat1) * Math.cos(plat2) * Math.cos(pradtheta);
                      pdist = Math.acos(pdist);
                      pdist = pdist * 180/Math.PI;
                      pdist = pdist * 60 * 1.1515;
                      pdist = pdist * 1.609344;
                      if(pdist<10){

        var postalLatlang = new google.maps.LatLng(value.latitude, value.longitude);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: postalLatlang,
            map: map,
            title: value.content
            });
            bounds.extend(marker.position);

        map.fitBounds(bounds);

      } 
                } else {
                    alert("Request failed.");
                }
            });
        }); 
    });
  });
```

Its working perfectly fine. But the issue is that when User search again(after searching with one postal address) at that time markers are not getting updated. It just add another marker(s).

So how can I remove/clear marker on every click of search? Is there any way ? I have went through Google Documentation, but I am not able to make it in right way.

**NOTE**: I need to stick with JSON file for adding marker.

Comment: How about keeping the same marker on the map but only changing it's position using `marker.setPosition(newPosition)` (newPosition would be your `new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)`)

Comment: Is there any way other than this ? Coz Its bit tricky I guess :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your markers in an array, and when you want to delete them, make a loop and

```
markers[i].setMap(null);
```

This is [how google does it](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove?hl=es)

Hope it helps.

Comment: `setMap` is function or it is global in google Map ?

Comment: Where should I add above line ? And how loop will work? Because my map is based on Click event ..

Comment: `var markers = [];
   markers.push(marker);
   for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
       markers[i].setMap(map);
     } ` 
This much I have done ..

Comment: take a look on the link included in my answer, use the functions as they do it there, in this case I would call `clearMarkers()` after `$(".search-btn").click(function(){`

Comment: I guess Its working on local ..:) I will accept that answer after giving another try. :)
Thanks for time dude ..

Comment: Yupp ... It worked !! But I mixed it with **Bradley Luke Totaro**'s solution. Your solution was working perfectly fine, but for particular postal address, it was not clearing.So I mixed and worked.
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

By rebuilding the map. you Don't keep an array of markers so you have to "Hack" it

```
var map;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 6
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
  mapOptions);

$(".search-btn").click(function(){
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
  mapOptions);
$.getJSON('path to json', function(data) { 
   $.each( data.markers, function(i, value) { 

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var postal = $("#postal").val(); //Take address from the user

        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': postal }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                var platitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var plongitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                //calculate distance
                  var plat1 = Math.PI * platitude/180;
                  var plat2 = Math.PI * value.latitude/180;
                  var plon1 = Math.PI * plongitude/180;
                  var plon2 = Math.PI * value.longitude/180;
                  var ptheta = plongitude-value.longitude;
                  var pradtheta = Math.PI * ptheta/180;
                  var pdist = Math.sin(plat1) * Math.sin(plat2) + Math.cos(plat1) * Math.cos(plat2) * Math.cos(pradtheta);
                  pdist = Math.acos(pdist);
                  pdist = pdist * 180/Math.PI;
                  pdist = pdist * 60 * 1.1515;
                  pdist = pdist * 1.609344;
                  if(pdist<10){

    var postalLatlang = new google.maps.LatLng(value.latitude, value.longitude);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: postalLatlang,
        map: map,
        title: value.content
        });
        bounds.extend(marker.position);

    map.fitBounds(bounds);

  } 
            } else {
                alert("Request failed.");
            }
        });
    }); 
});
});
```

added

`map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);`

after the button click event.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I think moving the marker would work

```
  var map;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var mapOptions = {
     zoom: 6
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  map: map
              });

  $(".search-btn").click(function(){

     $.getJSON('path to json', function(data) { 
         $.each( data.markers, function(i, value) { 

          var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
          var postal = $("#postal").val(); //Take address from the user

              geocoder.geocode({ 'address': postal }, function (results, status) {
                  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                      var platitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                      var plongitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                      //calculate distance
                        var plat1 = Math.PI * platitude/180;
                        var plat2 = Math.PI * value.latitude/180;
                        var plon1 = Math.PI * plongitude/180;
                        var plon2 = Math.PI * value.longitude/180;
                        var ptheta = plongitude-value.longitude;
                        var pradtheta = Math.PI * ptheta/180;
                        var pdist = Math.sin(plat1) * Math.sin(plat2) + Math.cos(plat1) * Math.cos(plat2) * Math.cos(pradtheta);
                        pdist = Math.acos(pdist);
                        pdist = pdist * 180/Math.PI;
                        pdist = pdist * 60 * 1.1515;
                        pdist = pdist * 1.609344;
                        if(pdist<10){

          var  postalLatlang = new google.maps.LatLng(value.latitude, value.longitude);

              marker.setTitle(value.content);
              marker.setPosition(postalLatlang)

              bounds.extend(marker.position);

              map.fitBounds(bounds);

        } 
                  } else {
                      alert("Request failed.");
                  }
              });
          }); 
      });
    });`
```